# Set default product

Tags: products

I want to set a default product in *Mathematica* in place of the standard product. Specifically, I want to change the standard product for `CenterDot` so that when I perform `A.B`, where `A` and `B` are two matrices, the multiplication **of the terms** is done using the `CenterDot`.

Alternatively, is there a way to perform specifying which product I want to use when performing the `A.B` operation?

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed example? If your question is too general, it  is highly possible that you will not get answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution. To use the function `Inner` with the functions `Plus` and `CenterDot`. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ However, I have a question, hope you can help me. I am trying to implement this in something that looks like `Sum[A^i, {i, 0, l}]`. Where A is a matrix. However, I want that "power" to be the `A.A.A....A` i times, using `CenterDot` to multiply the terms.

Comment: So, what is it?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I edited my question in the comment above

Comment: Kind of like this answer: `matrixlist=Table[M[j],{j,1,n}]
Apply[Dot,matrixlist]` but instead of `Dot`, `Inner`. I cannot just apply it like that because `Inner` expects me to tell it the operations I want to use.

Comment: Try this: `Clear[mymatrixpower];
mymatrixpower[A_, 0] := 1;
mymatrixpower[A_, i_] := CenterDot @@ Table[A, i];`

Comment: It does not quite work, the output of that is `MatrixForm[{{0, Subscript[o, 1, 2], Subscript[o, 1, 3]}, 
       {-Subscript[o, 1, 2], 0, 
    Subscript[o, 2, 3]}, {-Subscript[o, 1, 3], 
         -Subscript[o, 2, 3], 0}} \[CenterDot] {{0, 
    Subscript[o, 1, 2], Subscript[o, 1, 3]}, 
       {-Subscript[o, 1, 2], 0, 
    Subscript[o, 2, 3]}, {-Subscript[o, 1, 3], 
         -Subscript[o, 2, 3], 0}}]`

Comment: `MatrixForm[{{-(Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2]) - 
         Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3], 
       -(Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3]), 
   Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] 
         Subscript[o, 2, 3]}, {Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] 
    Subscript[o, 2, 3], 
       -(Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 2]) - 
    Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] 
              Subscript[o, 2, 3], -(Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] 
      Subscript[o, 1, 3])}, 
     {-(Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3])'

Comment: `Subscript[o, 1, 2] \[CenterDot] 
         Subscript[o, 1, 
     3], -(Subscript[o, 1, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 1, 3]) - 
         Subscript[o, 2, 3] \[CenterDot] Subscript[o, 2, 3]}}]`

Comment: Those two last comments are the desired outputs. The one you sent me does not quite preserve the size of the matrix. This is because you are applying `CenterDot` to the matrices. What I want is to apply `Inner` to the matrices using `CenterDot` as the product operation instead of `Times` as `Dot` uses.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ, I solved it implementing a `While`. Thank you very much!

Comment: could you please make your answer more explicit please. Presently its not exactly clear what the question/ the answer is.